# In ODOO How to specify different routing for different variants under same product?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, stock

By default for every product templates routing is buy. But in my case some variants are needed to set routing as make to order and some products needed to be set as manufacture and make to order. But if i change the routing for a product variant, then for all the other variants under the template will also get changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with add *route_ids* in *product.product* object.

For example:

```
class ProductProduct(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.product'

    route_ids = fields.Many2many('stock.location.route', 'stock_route_product',
        'product_id', 'route_id', 
        'Routes', domain="[('product_selectable', '=', True)]",
        help="Depending on the modules installed, this will allow you to define the route of the product: whether it will be bought, manufactured, MTO/MTS,...")
```

With these, we need to update/select routing for each variants of Product template and it will not update others product variants routing.

Comment: this is what I had tried.stock_route_product is the relation table specified in product template. so I changed the relation table name also. still not working

Comment: Do not change *stock_route_product* table and try it. I have tested at my end and it work fine. And upgrade/uninstall/reinstall your custom module.

Comment: still not working here. Also how can we specify the same relation table as stock_route_product is used for relation between product template and route. So if we use the same table, then it should show an error right as the id of template and varients are different

Comment: Please correct me. Relation table will store two id and column name as *product_id* and *route_id*. That's doesn't mean with weather a *product.product* id or *product.template* id.

Comment: yes you are correct. let me say an example.template with id 3 having some routes.as we are using the same table, when we open the product with id 3, it will have the same routes as that of the template with id3

Comment: This is not an answer. The OP is doing exactly what you're saying to do. FWIW, I'm having the exact same problem using the XMLRPC API.